# Behaviour of memset in C

Tags: c, memset

Consider the below structure

```
struct A
{
    int len;
    int wid;
    int size;
};

void main()
{
    struct A var;
    memset(&var,10,sizeof(struct A));
    printf("value of len is %d\n",var.len);
}
```

When I run the program, I was expecting that all the structure members will get initialized with 10 but it didn't happened. It was printing some junk value

But when I do memset with 0 or memset with 1 it works.

```
memset(&var,0,sizeof(struct A));
printf("value of len is %d\n",var.len);
```

Can someone please explain this behavior of memset

Comment: Read [memset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset)

Comment: You expected the output of `printf()` to be `10`. You expected wrongly. Consider. ;-) It doesn't print "some address", it prints *exactly* what you did set `var.len` to. Consider that as well. ;-)

Comment: This is not the same question as the alleged duplicate. That one was abourt arrays, this is about structs

Answer (score 3):

`memset` fills the memory with **byte** values. Your `int` members most probably need more than one byte (depending on your platform, four is quite common). So you're writing bytes and interpret them as `int`.

Your second example works as expected, because an all-zero representation of an `int` is required to be interpreted as the value `0`.